# How to start and stop jboss from apache ant build.xml file

Tags: ant, jboss, hudson

I have make 
jar
war
EAR

using ant and Hudson and store all files at some temp folder

now I want to copy all war and ear files to jboss jboss/default/deploy folder using Apache ANT

How can I do this??

Following is my master build file
which call all other build.xml files and make jar war ear files

but after making this all files this don't copy all any of the files to jboss/default/deploy folder

```
<copy todir="${jbossdeploy.dir}" overwrite="yes">
        <fileset dir="${class.dir}/ear" includes="MessageBoardEAR.ear"/>


    </copy>
```

---

```
<project name="master" >

    <property name="class.dir" location="../Source/buildwork" />
    <property name="ecpsproperties.dir" location="D:\ecpsproperties\jars\platform" />
    <property name="jbossdeploy.dir" location="D:\jboss-6.1.0.Final\server\default\deploy" />

    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="${class.dir}" />

    </target>

    <target name="makedir">
        <mkdir dir="${class.dir}" />
        <mkdir dir="${class.dir}/jar" />
        <mkdir dir="${class.dir}/ear" />
        <mkdir dir="${class.dir}/war" />
    </target>

<filelist id="projects" dir=".">
        <file name="../Source/ValueObjects/build.xml"/>
        <file name="../Source/ECPSValueObjects/build.xml"/>
        <file name="../Source/ECPSUtils/build.xml"/>
        <file name="../Source/CommonExceptions/build.xml"/>
         <file name="../Source/ECPSExceptions/build.xml"/>
         <file name="../Source/ECPSCommon/build.xml"/>
         <file name="../Source/BaseDAO/build.xml"/>
         <file name="../Source/PageManagerValueObjects/build.xml"/>
         <file name="../Source/PageManagerDAO/build.xml"/>
         <file name="../Source/ECPSDAO/build.xml"/>
         <file name="../Source/PageManagerEJBClient/build.xml"/>
         <file name="../Source/PartyEJBClient/build.xml"/>
          <file name="../Source/ReportsEJBClient/build.xml"/>
         <file name="../Source/StagingEJBClient/build.xml"/>
          <file name="../Source/MessageBoardEJBClient/build.xml"/>
         <file name="../Source/PageManagerFacade/build.xml"/>
          <file name="../Source/PartyFacade/build.xml"/>
         <file name="../Source/ReportsFacade/build.xml"/>
          <file name="../Source/StagingFacade/build.xml"/>
         <file name="../Source/MessageBoardFacade/build.xml"/>

          <file name="../Source/MessageBoardEJB/build.xml"/>
         <file name="../Source/MessageBoardEAR/build.xml"/>
         <file name="../Source/PageManagerEJB/build.xml"/>
          <file name="../Source/PageManagerEAR/build.xml"/>

           <file name="../Source/PartyEJB/build.xml"/>
         <file name="../Source/PartyEAR/build.xml"/>

         <file name="../Source/ReportsEJB/build.xml"/>
          <file name="../Source/ReportsEAR/build.xml"/>

          <file name="../Source/StagingEJB/build.xml"/>
         <file name="../Source/StagingEAR/build.xml"/>

          <file name="../Source/Admin/build.xml"/>
         <file name="../Source/eCPSClient/build.xml"/>
          <file name="../Source/MessageBoardServices/build.xml"/>
           <file name="../Source/OAuth/build.xml"/>
            <file name="../Source/PageManagerRest/build.xml"/>
             <file name="../Source/PartyServices/build.xml"/>
             <file name="../Source/ReportsServices/build.xml"/>
          <file name="../Source/StagingServices/build.xml"/>


 </filelist>



    <copy todir="${jbossdeploy.dir}" overwrite="yes">
        <fileset dir="${class.dir}/ear" includes="MessageBoardEAR.ear"/>


    </copy>




 <target name="main" depends="clean, makedir">
    <subant>

      <filelist refid="projects" />

    </subant>

 </target>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work as I have added copy task under main :

```
<project name="master" >

<property name="class.dir" location="../Source/buildwork" />
<property name="ecpsproperties.dir" location="D:\ecpsproperties\jars\platform" />
<property name="jbossdeploy.dir" location="D:\jboss-6.1.0.Final\server\default\deploy" />

<target name="clean">
<delete dir="${class.dir}" />

</target>

<target name="makedir">
<mkdir dir="${class.dir}" />
<mkdir dir="${class.dir}/jar" />
<mkdir dir="${class.dir}/ear" />
<mkdir dir="${class.dir}/war" />
</target>

<filelist id="projects" dir=".">
<file name="../Source/ValueObjects/build.xml"/>
<file name="../Source/ECPSValueObjects/build.xml"/>
<file name="../Source/ECPSUtils/build.xml"/>
<file name="../Source/CommonExceptions/build.xml"/>
<file name="../Source/ECPSExceptions/build.xml"/>
<file name="../Source/ECPSCommon/build.xml"/>
<file name="../Source/BaseDAO/build.xml"/>
<file name="../Source/PageManagerValueObjects/build.xml"/>
<file name="../Source/PageManagerDAO/build.xml"/>
<file name="../Source/ECPSDAO/build.xml"/>
<file name="../Source/PageManagerEJBClient/build.xml"/>
<file name="../Source/PartyEJBClient/build.xml"/>
<file name="../Source/ReportsEJBClient/build.xml"/>
<file name="../Source/StagingEJBClient/build.xml"/>
<file name="../Source/MessageBoardEJBClient/build.xml"/>
<file name="../Source/PageManagerFacade/build.xml"/>
<file name="../Source/PartyFacade/build.xml"/>
<file name="../Source/ReportsFacade/build.xml"/>
<file name="../Source/StagingFacade/build.xml"/>
<file name="../Source/MessageBoardFacade/build.xml"/>

<file name="../Source/MessageBoardEJB/build.xml"/>
<file name="../Source/MessageBoardEAR/build.xml"/>
<file name="../Source/PageManagerEJB/build.xml"/>
<file name="../Source/PageManagerEAR/build.xml"/>

<file name="../Source/PartyEJB/build.xml"/>
<file name="../Source/PartyEAR/build.xml"/>

<file name="../Source/ReportsEJB/build.xml"/>
<file name="../Source/ReportsEAR/build.xml"/>

<file name="../Source/StagingEJB/build.xml"/>
<file name="../Source/StagingEAR/build.xml"/>

<file name="../Source/Admin/build.xml"/>
<file name="../Source/eCPSClient/build.xml"/>
<file name="../Source/MessageBoardServices/build.xml"/>
<file name="../Source/OAuth/build.xml"/>
<file name="../Source/PageManagerRest/build.xml"/>
<file name="../Source/PartyServices/build.xml"/>
<file name="../Source/ReportsServices/build.xml"/>
<file name="../Source/StagingServices/build.xml"/>


</filelist>








<target name="main" depends="clean, makedir">
<subant>

<filelist refid="projects" />

</subant>

<copy todir="${jbossdeploy.dir}" overwrite="yes">
<fileset dir="${class.dir}/ear" includes="MessageBoardEAR.ear"/>


</copy>
</target>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

use copy task e.g.

```
<copy file="myfile.txt" todir="../some/other/dir"/>
```

Comment: I know this task but this is not executed while building build.xml file